# Does Azure File Service REST API support the concept of conditional operations?

Tags: rest, http, azure, azure-storage, http-caching

The documentation of Azure Files REST API lists some operations like [`GET File Metadata`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn689098.aspx) where response headers contain an ETag to serve this purpose

> The ETag contains a value that you can use to perform operations
>   conditionally, in quotes.

My modified requests with applied 'If-Modified-Since' header were responded by API with HTTP 403.

> 403 {'date': 'Wed, 05 Aug 2015 13:36:57 GMT', 'content-length': '729',
>   'content-type': 'application/xml', 'x-ms-request-id':
>   '3cdf88a2-001a-003f-4083-cf9725000000', 'server':
>   'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0'}

These were the request headers

> {'x-ms-version': '2014-02-14', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
>   'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.5.1 CPython/2.7.6
>   Linux/3.13.0-61-generic', 'Connection': 'keep-alive',
>   'If-Modified-Since': 'Tue, 04 Aug 2015 13:36:58 GMT', 'Authorization':
>   'SharedKey storage_account:secret_key', 'x-ms-date': 'Wed, 05 Aug 2015
>   13:36:58 GMT'}

Summary: The Azure Files REST API indicated no support for conditional operation, but permitted them. I did not find anything noteable in the documentation of Azure Files REST API.

The [documentation for Azure Blob Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179371.aspx) contains a section how to apply conditional headers.

> Several Blob service operations support the use of conditional
>   headers. You can specify conditional headers to carry out an operation
>   only if a specified condition has been met.
>
> The Blob service follows the HTTP/1.1 protocol specification for
>   conditional headers.

Does Azure File Service REST API support a similar concept of conditional operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have gone through the REST API documentation and as far as I can see, I can say that conditional operations are not supported in File Service in the current version of REST API. They may support it in future version though.